# C++ Transpose a Python regular expression into PCRE

Tags: python, c++, regex, pcre

I need to transpose a regular expression I wrote in Python into C++ using PCRE cpp wrapper.

My original python code does the following:

```
self.reg = re.compile('(?<![/,\-\s])\s+(?![/,\-\s])')

myfields = self.reg.split(line_of_text)
...
```

I tried to create a pcrecpp reg exp as follow:

```
pcrecpp::RE reg("(?<![/,\\-\\s])\\s+(?![/,\\-\\s])");
```

But it doesn't work. I mean PartialMatch() and FullMatch() do not work.
Moreover, I didn't find yet a method doing something similar to python re.split().
I'm not very experienced with PCRE. Is there a specific syntax ?

Any feedback ?

Thanks.

z.

Comment: you mean transform right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pcrecpp::RE](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/pcre/pcre-4.2/pcre/pcrecpp.h) class uses `/` as a delimiter ( *I believe..* ). The syntax is pretty similar to Perl's.

So you most likely need to escape the forward slash to fix your problem.

```
pcrecpp::RE re("(?<![\\/\\s,-])\\s+(?![\\/\\s,-])").PartialMatch("foo bar")
```

Comment: Hi hwnd, did you try your solution ? I just tested it but FullMatch("abc def") returned false.

Comment: Well, it works with PartialMatch() though ! So it seems my issue was the unescaped "/" character :(

Answer (score 1):

escape the forward slashes.

Like this:

```
(?<![\/,\-\s])\s+(?![\/,\-\s])
```